# Use JSON to create Model objects - Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have an external URL containing JSON.

So my question is: How do I save the JSON data to my Django admin page if I created the following model that matches the Keys of the JSON?

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    image_url = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    vote = models.IntegerField()
```

My goal is to be able to create a voting app that lets you vote for each individual person defined by the JSON.

Here is the longer version of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149309/create-object-models-from-external-json-link-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by running the following:

```
import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from urllib.request import urlopen
from .models import Person
from .serializers import PersonSerializer


class PersonView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        data = urlopen("<JSONURLHERE>").read()
        output = json.loads(data)
        persons = Person.objects.all()
        serializer = PersonSerializer(persons, many=True)
        for person in output:
            if person['id'] not in [i.id for i in persons]:
                Person.objects.create(id=person['id'], name=person['name'], image_url=person['image_url'],
                                          title=person['title'], bio=person['bio'])
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Where I'm basically creating objects using the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can use Model serializers for this end.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

And then you can use this PersonSerializer to populate the model with your `person_json` objects (in this case in an array of json objects) which you get from the REST API.

```
personSaver = PersonSerializer(data=person_json, many=True)
if personSaver.is_valid():
    personSaver.save()
```

Comment: I will try this, and let you know. I'm trying to create objects from a JSON file, so I can pass it into my HTML, and I want to be able to see the objects that were created based on this JSON, in my Admin page.