# Parsing JSON Response to Django DB

Tags: json, django, twilio

I am trying to save this Json response for Twilio to my DB but not sure how I parse this into my model in Django. At the moment it is just outputting the Json response to the terminal

```
def validate_order_with_details(request):
            try:
                client = Client(twillio_account_sid, twillio_auth_token)
                message = client.messages.create(
                    from_=twillio_from_no,
                    body=printer,
                    to=twillio_sender_mobile_no
                )
                if message:
                    return JsonResponse({"data": True, "printer": printer})
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({"data": True, "printer": "Error! while process twilio msg."})
                    print("There are an error with your transaction")
            except Exception as e:
                return JsonResponse({"data": True, "printer": str(e)})
                print("There are an error with your transaction")
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"data": False})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165237/use-json-to-create-model-objects-django
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022142/django-create-and-save-a-model-using-json-data

pick one

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this error with the below. I just needed to run the query to update my DB

```
def validate_order_with_details(request):
        try:
            client = Client(twillio_account_sid, twillio_auth_token)
            message = client.messages.create(
                from_=twillio_from_no,
                body=printer,
                to=twillio_sender_mobile_no
            )
            if message:
                # Save the Twilio SID to the database so we can look it up later to see if the message was delivered
                Order.objects.filter(id=order_id).update(twilio_sid=message.sid)
                Order.objects.filter(id=order_id).update(twilio_status=message.status)
                return JsonResponse({"data": True, "printer": printer})

            else:
                
                return JsonResponse({"data": True, "printer": "Errore! while process twilio msg."})
                print("There are an error with your transaction")
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({"data": True, "printer": str(e)})
            print("There are an error with your transaction")
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"data": False})
```